# My Dell inspiron 1464 bluetooth adapters does not work in ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, bluetooth

My Dell inspiron 1464 bluetooth adapters does not work in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

How to fix this?

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:6480 Microdia Sonix 1.3 MP Laptop Integrated Webcam
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1c4f:0003 SiGma Micro HID controller
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 198f:0220 Beceem Communications Inc. BCSM250 WiMAX Adapter
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 413c:8161 Dell Computer Corp. Integrated Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 413c:8162 Dell Computer Corp. Integrated Touchpad [Synaptics]
```

Answer (score -1):

What do you get when you run rfkill list ?

Sample output (from my Acer laptop) is:

phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: i2400m-usb:1-1.5:1.0: WiMAX
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
4: acer-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

Secondly, on some Dell laptops (e.g. Studio 15) you have to switch the Bluetooth mode from HID to HCI using

## hid2hci

You can install the tool by running:

sudo apt-get -y install hid2hci

Refer to the man file by running man hid2hci or refer to http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jaunty/man8/hid2hci.8.html

Good luck.